# Get excel file from pdf

Tags: adobe, ocr, pdf-java-toolkit

I receive a computer filled form which was printed and then scanned into PDF format file.

I want to convert that PDF to some structured format(like Acrobat does in Excel) so that I could extract the data. I had tried this using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC software which works smooth and gives me desirable results. The problem is I want to achieve the same using Java.

[Using Adobe DC SDK,convert pdf files to html files](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2164663)

[Java SDK for Acrobat Pro DC](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1849095)

I have read the above two discussions and found that it is not possible in java by first thread and the second thread says that Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit does not include export functions.

I created a trial account and navigated to "https://cloud.acrobat.com/exportpdf"
I get this error while subscribing to the service

[image]

Can someone route me to the ReST endpoint so that I could convert using JavaScript itself, as I was unable to find it.

Alternatives are also welcomed but the constraint is that the data extracted from scanned PDF should be similar to what Acrobat gives as output(structured in some way) because later I store that information to be used in another service.

Comment: While Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit does not directly export to Excel, you can use Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit to get the information out of PDF Form fields and into a CSV file that can be opened in Excel. See http://blogs.datalogics.com/2017/05/16/exporting-form-data-for-csv/